# How to show multiple message on validation in single alert box - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$(function()
{
$("#btnMessage").click(function()
{
    var name = $("#txtName").val();
    var phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
    var pizzaBase = $("#cboBase").val();
    var pizzaSize = $("input[name=radSize]:checked").val();
    message = "";


    if (name == "")
    {
        message += "--Enter a name\n";
    }

    if (phone == "")
    {
        message += "--Enter a valid phone number - 999-999-9999\n";
    }

    if (pizzaBase == "0")
    {
        message += "--Select a base pizza\n";
    }

    if (pizzaSize == undefined)
    {
        message += "--Select a pizza Size";

    }



    /*else 
    {
        message = name;

        alert(total);
    }*/


});

});
```

So here if i miss something in validation process. i.e if i miss the name and everything . How can i make the alert show that message variable?
Under which if statement it is meant to be ?

Comment: doesn't `alert(message);` work for you?

Comment: it does , but i am not sure that where to place it ? If i put it outside the if statements , even if validations is correct it still shows a empty alert.

Comment: put it at the end with another if statement like this `if(message) alert(message);`

Comment: Thanks a lot Hopeless , adding it under another if statement made it work like the way i wanted.

Comment: If possible can you tell me that if i have to use the message in Else statement , as i have to add the pizzaBase and pizzaSize  , should i make another variable instead of message ? for ex total ?

Comment: yes, if message is not empty, you should stop all processing to request user to provide all required info first. So in the `else` clause, you can put your processing there. Or you can also use `return;` after `alert...` like this `if(message) { alert(message); return; }`. You can make a variable to hold the total, it depends on how you use with that value.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function()
{
$("#btnMessage").click(function()
{
    var name = $("#txtName").val();
    var phone = $("#txtPhone").val();
    var pizzaBase = $("#cboBase").val();
    var pizzaSize = $("input[name=radSize]:checked").val();
    message = "";


    if (name == "")
    {
        message += "--Enter a name\n";
    }

    if (phone == "")
    {
        message += "--Enter a valid phone number - 999-999-9999\n";
    }

    if (pizzaBase == "0")
    {
        message += "--Select a base pizza\n";
    }

    if (pizzaSize == undefined)
    {
        message += "--Select a pizza Size";

    }



    if(message)
    {
       alert(total);
    } else {
      //Continue your processing
    }


});

});
```

Comment: Thanks it helped  :) , was my first question in this site and i am impressed already . Ty everyone